# Dynamicall add two form fileds to form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want add fisrst name and last name fields dynamically to my form. Currenltly I managed to add one field. but how can I add two fields once.

```
Ex: fname  lastname
    fname  lastname (X remove)
    fname  lastname (X remove)
    (+ add)
```

my code

html

## below is my html code ser

```
 <div class="input_fields_wrap">
   <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>  
    // I want to add another field with this
        </div>
         <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
```

## js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 20; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); 
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); 

    var x = 1;
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ 
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); 
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){             e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this will work for you:-

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 20; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); 
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); 
    var fname_lname = '<div>First Name:- <input type="text" name="fname"/>Last Name:- <input type="text" name="fname"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'

    var x = 1;
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ 
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append(fname_lname); 
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){             e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent().remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

checkout the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/dhruv1992/em1je2cu/

Answer (score 1):

So first, I removed the hardcoded HTML from your javascript. Then, I moved that to a HIDDEN template element, and just loaded its inner HTML as my template element -- by doing this, I can create as many elements as I might want.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      var max_fields = 20; //maximum input boxes allowed
      var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap");
      var add_button = $(".add_field_button");

      var x = 1;
      $(add_button).click(function(e) {
        // Here, I load the template's HTML
        var myFullTemplate = $(".fields-template").html();
        ''
        e.preventDefault();
        if (x < max_fields) {
          x++; //text box increment
          $(wrapper).append(myFullTemplate);
        } else {
          $(".add_field_button").hide();
        }
      });

      $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $(this).parent('div').remove();
          x--;
          if ($(".add_field_button").is(":hidden")) {
              $(".add_field_button").show();
            }
          })
      });
```

```css
.fields-template {
  display: none;
}
label {
  font-weight: bolder;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="mytext[]">
  </div>
  // I want to add another field with this
</div>
<button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>

<div class="fields-template">
  <div>
    <label for="fname">First name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="fname[]" />
    <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lname[]" /><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, to do what you mention in your comment (remove both fields rather than one), simply edit your HTML template to suit your needs. Also, another change: when you hit your max number of items, the add button is hidden (and when you delete one, it shows again).

Comment: I want to add two fields , but one remove for both. which means one row contain fname lname together with one remove button. so if one removed both will remove.

Comment: Try it again -- I've edited the HTML to do what you want. Made NO changes to the script at all.